# Qual o melhor método de autenticação do ASP.NET MVC 4?

Tags: c#, asp.net

Estou com dúvidas de como implementar uma melhor forma de autenticação, que seja segura e permita "sessões" ou "cookies" com nomes diferentes, possibilitando a criação de um método de autenticação para usuários e administradores de forma separada (sem que o cookie de um interfira no do outro) ou que necessite trabalhar com roles para definir o acesso de cada um.

1. Há algum método de autenticação padrão do ASP.NET que funcione desta forma?
2. Para autenticação no ASP.NET é melhor (mais seguro) utilizar Session o Cookie? caso não haja um método padrão do ASP.NET que possua o que descrevi mais acima.